# DataTables - Ignore 01/01/0001 moment date values when sorting

Tags: jquery, datatable

I have a last day activity column in the data table. If the table row contains the default value of date like **01/01/0001** in the date column I just replace the **no activity** text.
Problem is that when sorting the last activity date column date not sort. How can I sort the data table column when the date column has some text against default value of date.

I am using this code it is working fine with null dates. Please help.
Thanks in advance!

```
          (function (factory) {
            if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
                define(["jquery", "moment", "datatables.net"], factory);
            } else {
                factory(jQuery, moment);
            }
            }
            (function ($, moment) {

            $.fn.dataTable.moment = function (format, locale, reverseEmpties) {
                var types = $.fn.dataTable.ext.type;

                // Add type detection
                types.detect.unshift(function (d) {
                    if (d) {
                        // Strip HTML tags and newline characters if possible
                        if (d.replace) {
                            d = d.replace(/(<.*?>)|(\r?\n|\r)/g, '');
                            //d = d.replace('No Activity', '');
                        }

                        // Strip out surrounding white space
                        d = $.trim(d);
                    }

                    // Null and empty values are acceptable
                    if (d === '' || d === null) {
                        debugger
                        return 'moment-' + format;
                    }

                    return moment(d, format, locale, true).isValid() ?
                        'moment-' + format :
                        null;
                });

                // Add sorting method - use an integer for the sorting
                types.order['moment-' + format + '-pre'] = function (d) {
                    if (d) {
                        // Strip HTML tags and newline characters if possible
                        if (d.replace) {
                            d = d.replace(/(<.*?>)|(\r?\n|\r)/g, '');
                        }

                        // Strip out surrounding white space
                        d = $.trim(d);
                    }

                    return !moment(d, format, locale, true).isValid() ?
                        (reverseEmpties ? -Infinity : Infinity) :
                        parseInt(moment(d, format, locale, true).format('x'), 10);
                };
            };

        }));
```

Comment: where is your table html?

Comment: not an issue with the HTML table. it's a date sorting issue how to ignore the string no activity when sort date column

Comment: you need to know that Data Table requires `well formated` html table, with a header and single body, check out this
https://datatables.net/manual/installation